# use of continue in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop that iterates each row of an excel file. With the data I retrieve from the single row I run some query that select or insert some data in my db. 
Example of one query I run:

```
if($error == ''){
    try{
       $s2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT anagrafiche.id_ndg FROM anagrafiche 
            WHERE anagrafiche.cod_fisc = '$cf_cedente' 
            OR anagrafiche.p_iva = '$cf_cedente' 
            OR anagrafiche.cf_estero = '$cf_cedente'");
       $s2->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        $error = 'Errore nel trovare anagrafica cedente: '.$e->getMessage();    
        echo 'Non trovato cedente con codice fiscale '.$cf_cedente.' ';             
    }                   
}
```

This situation ends up with a lot of nested if because I don't want some query to run if an error is thrown at a specific point.
Would it be better in terms of execution time or resources if I use continue to stop the current row to be executed and jump to the next instead of this situation? So that the code would look like:

```
try{
    $s2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT anagrafiche.id_ndg FROM anagrafiche 
        WHERE anagrafiche.cod_fisc = '$cf_cedente' OR anagrafiche.p_iva = 
        '$cf_cedente' OR anagrafiche.cf_estero = '$cf_cedente'");
    $s2->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    $error = 'Errore nel trovare anagrafica cedente: '.$e->getMessage();    
    echo 'Non trovato cedente con codice fiscale '.$cf_cedente.' ';         
}                   
if($error!=''){
    echo $error;
    continue;
}
```

Or there is an even better option I haven't thought about yet? 
Thank you for your help!
Note: I am doing a massive data load so I need continue to load the next row skipping the one that is in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the php manual,

> [`continue`](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the
>   current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition
>   evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

whereas

> [`break`](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.

both keywords accept an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures should skipped to the end of / broken out of.

So yes, if an error only affects one row, use `continue;` to skip to the next row. If an error encountered in a single row is fatal and affects all rows, use `break;` to end the `foreach` loop.